# How to export and migrate OpenSlides database?

Tags: python, django

I encountered an error message while exporting my OpenSlides database. My goal is to switch from a SQLite database to PostgreSQL database in OpenSlides, but unfortunately, as I said, exporting doesn't quite work.

Can someone help me please?

Error Message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'

[image: My error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. You have to enter `openslides createsettings` so that the settings file is created first.
Then it can find the settings.py